# IOS different app icon depending on the device used

Tags: ios, swift, icons

I can already detect which device is being used by the user (from iPhone 4 to latest and also the iPad etc.) my question is, is there any code or method for me to change the app icon **depending on the device used**?

Comment: actualy you cant set the same app icon for different devices because of resolution

Comment: how do you set app icon?

Comment: as of now, I'm doing the standard way of "assigning" icon for the application. (Choose Editor > Add Assets > App Icons & Launch Images > New iOS App Icon etc). 

I have unique icons for each devices (for example: icon1 is for iPhone 4, icon2 is for iPhone 5 and so on) it's not possible to use these unique icons depending on the device?

Comment: [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Comment: thank you @evnaz for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't do this.
However you can add different images for different resolution, but Apple won't approve your app.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. This will help me prove to my client that it is impossible.

Comment: @Scar: You are welcome.Also you can use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html as a reference. Happy coding